# Use of int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

How to use **int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway**
to invoke Stored procedure(oracle) with IN parameter as Object?

I am using the below statements for the same.

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway id="contract.batch.xyz.jdbc.storedproc.gateway" data-source="dataSource" request-channel="contract.batch.com.classfn.service.activator.out" skip-undeclared-results="true" stored-procedure-name="country_pkg.set_country_name" >
<int-jdbc:parameter name="p_country_tbl" expression="payload" />
```

But here I am sending list of objects to `"p_country_tbl"` , please suggest me .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you have a list of objects and you you want to invoke the stored procedure for each object, add a `<splitter/>` before the gateway.